# How to Compare dates in using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I have some problem with comparing dates

```
 DateTime from = DateTime.Parse(sFromDate);
 DateTime to = DateTime.Parse(sToDate);

 return orderLambda(objCouponUow.Repository<CouponGuids>().Entities.Where(x=> x.OrderCreatedDate <= to && x.OrderCreatedDate >= from));
```

the strings are  sFromDate='29/05/2014 00:00:00' and sToDate='31/05/2014 00:00:00'
Here am not getting error

Pls Give a solution

Comment: Hopefully, in SQL Server, the dates are in a `date` or `datetime2` column and so do not **have** a format. You've shown your attempt - what happens when you run it?

Comment: You *would* get an error with the code you've given, by the way... so either that isn't the code you've given, or you've misdiagnosed things. You haven't told us what actually happens though.

Comment: "Here am not getting error" - so what *does* happen? What is the symptom / problem that you are seeing?

Comment: Sorry it doesnot return the rows between the given dates

Comment: Please pay more attention when you're asking a question next time, to avoid wasting people's time chasing problems which aren't actually in your real code. Have you validated that the dates are parsing correctly? What's the type of the `OrderCreatedDate` field in the database?

Comment: Sorry. Type Of OrderCreatedDate is Datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates are not in *any* format in SQL Server, unless you are storing them wrong. If you view them in SSMS then it *renders* them in a format, for your viewing convenience. But they are actually just numbers (integer part is days into epoch, decimal part is time).

So just order/filter them *by date, as dates*.

Comment: Would be relevant if the code above would even compile and not be a simple "never bothered to look at the compiler error" issue. Also the format is irrelevant as - this is not a string comparison. -1.

Comment: @TomTom nice; it addresses a number of misconceptions and misunderstanding that are pivotal in the phrasing of the question. I don't see how that is irrelevant. Your choice, though.

Comment: @TomTom: Marc's point is that there is no format to *be* relevant.